# Upload infected .exe to remote location to run it

Tags: executable, remote-desktop, virus, trojan

Is there any service where you can upload a .exe that you know has a virus, and they let you run it there remotely?

thanks

Comment: Are you sure you want to run the virus? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this might be a good use of VMWare.

Comment: thanks for your answer. as it just so happens, I installed Win 7 a few days ago and used the XP virtual machine with Undo Disks ON, ran the file in it, and then deleted the Undo Disk. Thanks for your idea it worked out great

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Sunbelt's online malware analyzer](http://www.sunbeltsecurity.com/sandbox/) for one option.

Comment: thanks, but my question wasn't how to know it's infected. I know that it is infected, I just want to run it somewhere